# ItemClickListener RecycleView Firebase

Tags: java, android

**i have recycleview and i retrive data from firebase..i want to show dialog in itemclick to show data of user**

that my code and settext in show dialog but error showing that null data

```
public void showdialog(){

    TextView exist;
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.doctor_info);
    exist=dialog.findViewById(R.id.exist);
    exist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    dialog.show();


    //dspecialize.setText(doctors.get(position).getName());
    //dcity.setText(doctors.get(position).getName());



}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    doctors.get(position).getName();
    doctors.get(position).getAddress();
    doctors.get(position).getMail();
    doctors.get(position).getPhone();
    dname.setText(doctors.get(position).getName());
    dmail.setText(doctors.get(position).getMail());
    daddress.setText(doctors.get(position).getAddress());
    dgender.setText(doctors.get(position).getGender());
    dphone.setText(doctors.get(position).getPhone());

    showdialog();
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code, including the stacktrace and the surrounding code. It seems you are showing where it breaks not where the problem first occurs.

Comment: If it says null data , then it means you have not retreived data from firebase quite well. Post the code wherein you get the data from Firebase along with the recyclerview adapter .